# take means of one vector by factors define in a different vector

Tags: r

let us say I have two vectors,

```
v1 = c(1,2,1,4,5,6,2,2,4,5,5,6)
v2 = c('lo', 'lo', 'la', 'la', 'la', 'li', 'li', 'li', 'li', 'lo', 'li', 'la')
```

I want to take the mean of `v1`, by the groups (`lo, la, li`) defined in `v2`.  What is an efficient way to do it without looping over?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is standard fare for `tapply`:

```
tapply(v1, v2, mean)
#       la       li       lo 
# 4.000000 3.800000 2.666667
```

---

Also, a fun approach might be:

```
xtabs(v1 ~ v2)/table(v2)  ## sum divided by length
```

If I were to *guess* (someone else is free to actually do the benchmarks), I would think that `tapply` and `by` would be very close in performance in this case. The `xtabs` + `table` shouldn't be too slow, but would definitely be slower because of the double tabulation. Because of all of the conversion to `data.frame`, attempts to simplify the output, and so on, I would imagine `aggregate` to be the slowest approach.

Comment: "standard fare"...I like it.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto You are correct, xtabs is slow but not as that of aggregate. Please check the benchmarks.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto.  On a bigger dataset, data.table() approach wins.  I will update it shortly, followed by rapply().  I should have included dplyr also.  I will try it when I get more time :-)

Answer (score 3):

Or `aggregate`

```
aggregate(v1 ~ v2, FUN = mean)

##   v2       v1
## 1 la 4.000000
## 2 li 3.800000
## 3 lo 2.666667
```

Comment: Aaarrgghhh... Fix dem names!!! `aggregate(v1 ~ v2, FUN=mean)` (also, `aggregate` and `by` are mostly "convenience" functions for the `tapply` workhorse, if I'm not mistaken) :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto, fixed the names... :) It's hard to compete for speed with you what can I say. You have to get some special tag for answering before the question even posted

Comment: There was a hat for that for Christmas, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 2):

`by` would also work for this.

```
> by(v1, v2, mean)
# v2: la
# [1] 4
# --------------------------------------------------- 
# v2: li
# [1] 3.8
# --------------------------------------------------- 
# v2: lo
# [1] 2.666667
```

And that can be  wrapped with `c()` to turn the result into a vector

```
> c(by(v1, v2, mean))
#       la       li       lo 
# 4.000000 3.800000 2.666667
```

or wrapping with `as.table` will turn the result into a table.

Comment: I was just going to add that.  Haha

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be:

```
  rapply(split(v1,v2), mean)
 #     la       li       lo 
 #  4.000000 3.800000 2.666667
```

#### Speed comparison

```
  set.seed(1)
  v1 <- sample(100, 1000000, TRUE)
  v2 <- paste0(LETTERS, sample(10, 1000000, TRUE))


 fun1 <- function() rapply(split(v1,v2), mean)
 fun2 <- function() tapply(v1, v2, mean)
 fun3 <- function() aggregate(v1~v2, FUN=mean)
 fun4 <- function() c(by(v1, v2, mean))
 fun5 <- function() xtabs(v1~v2)/table(v2)
 library(data.table) #included data.table method based on comments from @Ananda Mahto
 fun6 <- function() data.table(v1, v2)[, mean(v1), by=v2]

 library(dplyr)
 fun7 <- function() {df <- data.frame(v1,v2)
           df%>% group_by(v2)%>% 
          summarize(v1=mean(v1))}


 library(microbenchmark)
 microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2(), fun3(), fun4(), fun5(), fun6(), fun7())
 #Unit: milliseconds         
 #      expr         min          lq      median          uq        max neval
 # fun1()    61.49778    72.11014    93.77996    99.80158   507.7508   100
 # fun2()    96.37805   112.37573   144.92092   161.54825   501.7165   100
 # fun3() 10766.64464 12218.22933 16041.39458 16500.57674 24669.4982   100
 # fun4()   119.83302   138.58920   175.82427   190.05616   730.4116   100
 # fun5()   356.93513   445.36760   521.84018   594.67285  2117.1304   100
 # fun6()    16.31299    18.67497    23.36138    25.72171   130.0437   100
 # fun7()    78.79703    93.90406   119.69846   127.98684   454.6454   100
```

Comment: I'm a little surprised by the speed differences. What size vectors did you use? How many groups?

Comment: I take that back. My assumption seems to scale along the same lines too :-). Nice work with the `rapply(split(...))` approach.

Comment: Of course, there are even other options for speed, like using "data.table". Example to add (with bigger data): `set.seed(1); v1 <- sample(100, 1000000, TRUE); v2 <- paste0(LETTERS, sample(10, 1000000, TRUE)); fun6 <- function() data.table(v1, v2)[, mean(v1), by = v2]`

Comment: @Ananda Mahot. Thanks.  I thought about including `data.table()`, `dplyr`, but it needs conversion to data.table or data.frame objects.  By doing the microbenchmark on the same dataset, data.table  `fun6() 1252.569 1333.149 1365.872 1398.9445  5631.151   100`.  For larger datasets, it would be better.

Comment: Does benchmarking on a small dataset like this even make sense? Maybe I don't value my time enough, but I won't miss any sleep over a few hundred microseconds :-)